# Convert string array to numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I'm attempting to convert the string `'[ 0.  0.  1.]'` to a numpy array.

This is the code I've written but is more complicated that needs be ?

```
arr = []
s = '[ 0.  0.  1.]'
arr.append(int(s.split(" ")[1].replace("." , '')))
arr.append(int(s.split(" ")[3].replace("." , '')))
arr.append(int(s.split(" ")[5].replace("]" , '').replace("." , '')))

arr = np.array(arr)

print(arr)
print(type(arr))
print(type(arr[0]))
```

Above code prints :

```
[0 0 1]
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
<class 'numpy.int64'>
```

Is there a cleaner method to convert string '[ 0.  0.  1.]' to numpy int array type ?

Comment: depends on how flexible you want to be. `np.array(s[1:-1].split(), float).astype(int)`

Comment: or even `np.matrix(s).A1.astype(int)`

Comment: @PaulPanzer s = '[ 0.  0.  1.]'
np.matrix(s) returns 'TypeError: Invalid data string supplied: ['

Comment: Strange, it works for me. Which versions are you on?

Comment: Looks like it changed sometime during 1.13.x. So if you are 1.12 or less you'll have to do `np.matrix(s[1:-1]).A1.astype(int)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Numpy as can handle it much easier than all the answers:

```
s = '[ 0.  0.  1.]'
np.fromstring(s[1:-1],sep=' ').astype(int)
```

Answer (score 0):

IN:

```
import numpy as np

s = '[ 0.  0.  1.]'

out = np.array([int(i.replace('.','')) for i in s[s.find('[')+1:s.find(']')].split()])

print(type(out))
```

OUT:

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>
```