# Unable to convert String to numpy 1d array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

For facial recognition, we need to read vector from mysql DB and convert to 1D array for recognition.

The following object is retrieved from mysql which is stored as JSON format in mysql.

```
s1= [-0.12783311307430267, 0.13190957903862, 0.09596485644578934, -0.09712248295545578, -0.11780811846256256, 0.007217485923320055, -0.11222986876964568, -0.04876283556222915, 0.2216355949640274, -0.10998672991991044, 0.18791022896766665, 0.08736929297447205, -0.16356715559959412, -0.01818229630589485, -0.021847818046808243, 0.13041044771671295, -0.13738003373146057, -0.09671961516141891, -0.02172057516872883, -0.14230197668075562, 0.05242226645350456, 0.09029272198677064, -0.002328673377633095, 0.00397188076749444, -0.20264719426631927, -0.2703503370285034, -0.12626759707927704, -0.07806601375341415, 0.1267593950033188, -0.13493752479553223, -0.043157391250133514, -0.016596168279647827, -0.16287413239479065, -0.0656481683254242, 0.03958671912550926, 0.07427462935447693, -0.06913568824529648, -0.0629347711801529, 0.178871750831604, 0.08766687661409378, -0.09091204404830933, 0.011706589721143246, 0.04953945055603981, 0.27260822057724, 0.16323423385620117, 0.0253637433052063, 0.10930740833282472, -0.11138659715652466, 0.12710365653038025, -0.21879185736179352, 0.08703845739364624, 0.1319100558757782, 0.034353598952293396, 0.10928373038768768, 0.12201938033103944, -0.17505870759487152, 0.014886455610394478, 0.09721830487251282, -0.1538517326116562, 0.1672624796628952, 0.10802490264177322, -0.0300880316644907, -0.10113763064146042, -0.006332905497401953, 0.2025756984949112, 0.09179922193288804, -0.113119974732399, -0.20894797146320343, 0.15196490287780762, -0.12537285685539246, -0.05446625128388405, 0.11561021953821182, -0.11292491853237152, -0.11957288533449172, -0.2860523462295532, 0.08072254806756973, 0.4256277084350586, 0.15420164167881012, -0.11120182275772096, 0.0442705899477005, -0.06239746138453483, -0.043058544397354126, 0.03340786322951317, 0.06541167199611664, -0.12657742202281952, 0.017120834439992905, -0.03134886175394058, 0.10211298614740372, 0.20427383482456207, 0.03959937393665314, -0.01935926266014576, 0.2007918357849121, 0.051548801362514496, 0.08825849741697311, 0.016137562692165375, 0.1055104285478592, -0.15693385899066925, -0.07759833335876465, -0.0738161951303482, -0.05325906723737717, 0.08928476274013519, -0.09207655489444733, 0.035900089889764786, 0.17390793561935425, -0.17486083507537842, 0.20116952061653137, -0.03213610127568245, -0.03827217221260071, -0.05482873693108559, 0.07908175885677338, -0.14436912536621094, -0.010803371667861938, 0.1578456461429596, -0.2274101823568344, 0.18742960691452024, 0.2068897932767868, 0.04828779026865959, 0.08840855956077576, 0.11564983427524568, 0.051258377730846405, 0.0017237504944205284, 0.01801629178225994, -0.0783238410949707, -0.07523202151060104, -0.05354651063680649, -0.06916598975658417, 0.04159272089600563, 0.03667797893285751]

b = str(s1)

as1=np.fromstring(b, dtype=np.uint8, count=-1,sep=',')

print '-output--',as1

np.reshape(as1, (-1,1)
```

it is returning `array([], dtype=uint8)`

It tried all the below options but could not get it

[Convert string to numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28207743/convert-string-to-numpy-array)

[Convert string array to numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50881875/convert-string-array-to-numpy-array)

Comment: Use `json.loads` to convert it back to a list

Comment: 'uint8' with those numbers??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

`b = str(s1) # converting to string as your input is string
output = np.fromstring(b[1:-1],sep=',') # using b[1:-1] to get the string alone by slicing square braces ([])
print(output)`

check the [doc](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromstring.html) for more info

Comment: Thank u its running

Comment: This is the same as the accepted answer to your second link!

Answer (score 0):

If, as in your example, the string representation precisely reflects that of a regular Python list, you can use `ast.literal_eval` before feeding `np.array`:

```
from ast import literal_eval

as1 = np.array(literal_eval(b), dtype=np.uint8)

print(as1.dtype)

# uint8
```

The docs explain types accepted by [`literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

> Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python
>   literal or container display. The string or node provided may only
>   consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, bytes,
>   numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, sets, booleans, and `None`.

So we are effectively converting a string to a Python `list`, which `np.array` can then convert to a NumPy array.

---

If you are keen on using `np.fromstring`, note that open and close square brackets must be excluded:

```
as1 = np.fromstring(b[1:-1], sep=',').astype(np.uint8)
```

Note, as above, you will need to read as `float` first (the default) before conversion to `np.uint8`. In this case, you should expect all 0 values.